# Is vlc-qt able to get the RAW audio data?

Tags: qt, libvlc, vlc-qt

I am building a media player based on [vlc-qt](https://vlc-qt.tano.si/), and I want to add the music visualization feature to my application, but how can I get the raw audio data?

Comment: Good question!!